# How to handle process using multiple queues in sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, concurrency, queue, sidekiq

We have a requirement where we need to process things for each account separately. For this, we thought of using `multiple queues` so that process of that corresponding account is assigned and handled by the specific queue. Also we planned this because we would need to handle only one process for each account (i.e `concurrency`) in each queue. On looking into the `documentation`, we could see that "sidekiq" recommends to have not more than `handful of queues`. In our case there will more number of accounts and each account will have a multiple process. So how can we achieve our requirement and what should be the good practice or way to do it. We also need multiple queues because we are planning to pause or stop the process specific to the account and we hope this can be handled at ease, if we have specific queues.

If in case more queues are recommended in pro version we are ready to move but, how should we set `concurrency to 1` for each queue that needs to be added dynamically. Also tell us how we can handle adding more queues as the account grows?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your processing requirements are customized to the extent that a generic tool like Sidekiq isn't well suited to your needs.  Sidekiq isn't designed to add queues dynamically, nor is it designed to work well in systems with hundreds or thousands of queues.